# SQL Server 2005 : how to check for empty string

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a Procedure which returns MobileAreaCode+Mobile if they are not null
I just want to add to it support for empty strings as well I tried(without the handle for empty string it works)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE PROC_NAME
    @Identification INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
    CASE WHEN MobileAreaCode is NOT NULL OR Mobile is NOT NULL 
OR MobileAreaCode<>'' OR Mobile<>''
    THEN
        MobileAreaCode+Mobile
    END
    FROM 
        TABLE_NAME
    WHERE 
        id = 123456789
END
GO
```

which doesn't work and results the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Use [NULLIF (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx).

```
select nullif(MobileAreaCode, '')+nullif(Mobile, '') as MobileAreaCodeMobile
from YourTable
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2dd83/1)

Comment: i use execute scalar in my code and when i run the procedure, it return {} for null value(null value is when i call the procedure but the values in the columns are incorrect. How can i include that in an if statement in my code' something like *if(ExecuteScalar("Proc_name)!=null)* i use .net as language

Comment: I found the answer I just had to call "ToString" and ask if it !=""

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE PROC_NAME
@Identification INT
AS
BEGIN
SELECT 
CASE WHEN (MobileAreaCode is NOT NULL) AND (Mobile is NOT NULL) 
AND (len(MobileAreaCode)>0) AND (len(Mobile)>0)
THEN
    MobileAreaCode+Mobile
END
FROM 
    TABLE_NAME
WHERE 
    id = 123456789
END
GO
```

Comment: not working, for your answer above I get for the values Mobile='' and MobileAreaCode =555 ->555 as a result. (both are nvarchar(50)

Comment: check now. or is changed to and